# database table relation customising and structuring

Tags: sql-server, customization

This is merely an issues on design implementation on database table relation. I am looking for a practical way of designing it based on other user experiences and best practices.
A few information:

Database used: MSSQL

About the tables:

I have one "master" table which is used to hold information about a product, this are specific information which are used every time on all the products.

I have one "slave" table with different other information about the product, which may or may not be applicable to all of them, as the product may change and can have features that other might not have. 
Also, the additional information about the product might be: a string, a int, a bit etc.

What I am trying to achieve is to have full customisation on the product additional information, without the need of adding another column to the "slave" table, and to keep the same data definition that defines the column.

*So to sum up:

Have different tables where I can add/remove additional information and can be assigned to a ProductNo.

I can create from them a template table, so I don`t have to add 20 additional info from my software every time I add a new product.

Use the template table + additional info tables to assign them to new products.

For example a product might have a defined template but also some different additional info fields.*

My question:

What would be the best practice to implement this?

Update 1.

Example of what I use now:

```
Master Table:  

ProductNo       varchar(20) Primary Key  
CustomerNo      smallint  
TargetDate      date  
RecommitDate    date  
ShipDate        date
```

```
Slave Table(Additional Information) 
ProductNo     varchar(20) 
info1         smallint
info2         smallint
info3         smallint
info4         smallint
IsInfo5       bit   
IsInfo6       bit   
IsInfo7       bit   
IsInfo8       bit   
IsInfo9       bit   
Info10        smallint  
Info11        tinyint   
Info12        varchar(MAX)  
Info13        text  
Info14        varchar(30)
```

Update 2:

What I would like to achieve in example:

Slave tables:

```
Slave 1:
index         smallint
info          smallint

Slave 2:
index         smallint
IsInfo       bit    


Slave 3:
index        smallint
Info         varchar(MAX)
```

every table that holds that additional information to be able to hold only one type of data so I can add more in the future.
All the info from this tables to be able to relate them to the ProductNo from the Master Table in another table.

Comment: could you please explain with examples rather than words ?

Comment: Updated with an example of what I currently use.

Comment: what is the primary key field in the master table and in the slave table ?

Comment: The first table has first column as primary key the second table has none.

Comment: Do you mean making a relation between these tables ? you can do that like this : alter table [slave table] add constraint FK_Master foreign key (ProductNo) references [Master Table] (ProductNo)

Comment: I dont see any issues with your table design

Comment: I know there is no issue. I just want to make it flexible in the way I add new  additional information to the table and the way it relates to the Master table. For example see update 2.

Comment: It's obviously open schema, so why not use XML or JSON to hold the additional attributes? Or maybe sparse columns, did you check that?

Comment: The software I am developing is for multiple users. So if one user adds new info to xml files which are held locally it won`t make them available to other users. I am not familiar with JSON but will look in to it just to familiarise myself with. The software that will interact with the database is written in WPF C#.

Comment: I meant storing XML or JSON in the database, not on the file system.

Comment: Please, can you give me more details as I am not familiar with it. Thank you